# Split sheet by rule (filter) in Open Office

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, openoffice-base

I want to split a large sheet. I have different products and for each of them I would like a new file. Is it possible to split the sheet by some rule?

P.S. I am new in here, so if my question is somehow not appropriate, just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any easy way. If noone comes up with a better one, you could likely do what you need done via code by using something like perl. This is discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278090/how-can-i-create-or-read-openoffice-spreadsheets-from-perl